# UnitTest project can't reference other project in solution

Tags: c#, reference, projects

I added a unit test project (UnitTests) in Visual Studio and added a reference to the other project (CollectWords) in my solution, but I can only access one of the namespaces which is called "CollectWords". I have another namespace named "CollectWords.Service" with a class "ReviewService" and a static function "x()".

In one of my test files in the UnitTests project I added a reference to CollectWords.Service. So why doesn't this compile?

```
            CollectWords.Service.ReviewService.x();
```

It says it can't find "Services" in the namespace "CollectWords".

This is a screenshot of the solution explorer where you can see both the reference and the two projects.

[image]

Edit:
Fixed the code snippet. Namespace still doesn't show up on intellisense. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Is it .Service or .Services? There is an inconsistency in your question. Your code mentions Service where it looks like it should be Services

Comment: I discovered it. Fixed. I found the issue: I had not defined my class public, so it was only visible internally in the same assembly.